# WinForms different WebView instances need to share same session

Tags: wpf, winforms, webview, session-cookies, windows-community-toolkit

I am using latest Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit WebView control in a winforms class.

I am creating several WebView instances to navigate to different pages in same domain. But different WebView instances are not sharing same session.
In every navigate request, a new session is created.

So, Is there any configuration that provides different webview instances can share cookie for same domain?

CefSharp browser is providing this feature. So I believe there should be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Web views themselves share information, but not in real time. That is, if an application has two web views (1 and 2) initialized at the same time, they'll have forks of the current state. If web view 1 adds a new cookie, web view 2 will not have it (e.g. web view 2 is not notified of the state change); however, if web view 2 is initialized after web view 1, then it will have web view 1's state.

That said, this is far from ideal and is different behavior from other web views and even the Edge browser. Would you mind contributing to the backlog on the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AWebView)?